# C# DataGrid sorting by absolute value on dynamically created columns

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datagrid, absolute

I have DataGrid and columns are added dynamically because it can change based on user input.
I setup grid by :

this.grid.DataContext =  d;

where d is an instance of System.Data.DataTable().DefaultView

Columns are mostly in integers and I want to sort them by absolute values.   How do I do that?
In the past, I used "SortMemberPath" for static grid that has objects as underlying but I am not sure how I can do this on dynamically created one that contains bunch of numbers as columns.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem and requirement is. You have a `DataTable` which you want to sort according to the contained values? If so, can you show it so we know better what you want?

Comment: It is better to sort the datatable and then the grid should also automatically update.

Comment: Let's say I have values such as 20,-10, 5, -1.  When I click on column, I want it to short either 20,-10,-5,-1 or -1, -5, -10, 20 (using its absolute values).    For static grid, I accomplished this by using SortMemberPath but not sure how to do it for dynamically created grid.